# JS/Electron Add item one by one

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js, electron

Sorry if I can't explain myself well, i have a function(code below) that parse a json and create a grid of 1550 items, how can add them one by one and not all together?
Because this way work well but load 1500 takes time.

```
function additem () {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'list.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
      return
    }
    let json = JSON.parse(data)
    for (let i in json) {
      mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += '<a href="${json[i].desc}"><div class="cell" id=${i}>${json[i].title}</div> </a>'
      `)

    }
  })
}
```

In the code below i create the window, show a splash screen, and then show the main window. And then i call the function on app ready

```
function puziale () {
    splash = new BrowserWindow({width: 200, height: 200, transparent: true, frame: false, alwaysOnTop: true});
    (async ()=>{  
        createWindow(); 
        splash.loadFile('splash.html');  
        await sleep(2000);  
        splash.destroy();
        mainWindow.show()
        
      })();
 
    
    
}

app.on('ready', puziale);
```

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a good one. It is fundamental with async programming.
You should replace the function with:

### option A)

if the order of the items does **NOT** matter.

```
async function loop_iteration(json, i) {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += '<a href="${json[i].desc}"><div class="cell" id=${i}>${json[i].title}</div> </a>'
      `)
}

function additem () {
  fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'list.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
      return
    }
    let json = JSON.parse(data)
    for (let i in json) {
        loop_iteration(json, i);
    }
  })
}
```

This makes each loop iteration async - so each loop iteration is executed without waiting for the previous loop iterations.

### option B)

If the order of the items does matter.

The page doesn't freeze, but all iterations are executed at once.

```
async function loop(json) {
    for (let i in json) {
        mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`
        document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += '<a href="${json[i].desc}"><div class="cell" id=${i}>${json[i].title}</div> </a>'
      `)
    }
}

function additem() {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'list.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
            return
        }
        let json = JSON.parse(data)
        loop(json);
    })
}
```

This makes the whole loop async, so each loop iteration does wait for the previous iterations, so the user won't experience any stuck.
But it will execute all iterations at once... :(

To get the best of both worlds, you may consider doing this:

### option c)

Exactly what you imagined.

```
async function loop_iteration(json, i) {
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += '<a href="${json[i].desc}"><div class="cell" id=${i}>${json[i].title}</div> </a>'`)
}

async function loop(json) {
    for (let i in json) {
        await loop_iteration(json, i);
    }
}

function additem() {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'list.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
            return
        }
        let json = JSON.parse(data)
        loop(json);
    })
}
```

In this code, I tell the browser "Don't wait for the for loop to end, but each iteration that is being executed only after the last one is ended.

### Option D)

Loads the JSON with async benefits and execute and render the page only once.

```
async function loop_iteration(json, i, arr) {
    arr.push(`<a href="${json[i].desc}"><div class="cell" id=${i}>${json[i].title}</div> </a>`)
}

async function loop(json) {
    const arr = []
    for (let i in json) {
        await loop_iteration(json, i, arr);
    }
    mainWindow.webContents.executeJavaScript(`document.getElementById("grid").innerHTML += '${arr.join('')}'`)
}


function additem() {
    fs.readFile(path.join(__dirname, 'list.json'), 'utf8', (err, data) => {
        if (err) {
            alert('Could not read file.\n\nDetails:\n' + err.message)
            return
        }
        let json = JSON.parse(data)
        loop(json);
    })
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, i have implemented your code(the order doesn't matter), but sadly the ruslt is the same, all the item are loaded together.

Comment: (a) Can you try implementing option c and tell me the result?

(b) Can you extract a minimal code to demonstrate the issue? something I can copy to my electron project as-is and see it running so I can make test it on my side and give you a live demo. (like give me a link to the JSON and so on...)

Comment: I have tried the option c, is faster, but the problem remain, the window is blocked for 2/4 seconds, i create the json with a scraper script, wich part of code wouluud be helpful? i will add some in the question

Comment: Try no to call function "additem" at all, is the window still blocked for 2/4 seconds? If so, the problem is not that function. but if the window is not blocked - please, send me the whole project and I will examine this, this is very strange, on my side this is working well without any block. Anyway, if you find any of this helpful, feel free to upvote.

Comment: No, without the additem there is no blocked window. Well in the js there isn't much. I think the problem is that i have to render one item at a time, cause it stille load them as a "block"

Comment: In that case, I edit the answer and add option D, to simplify the rendering.